# bitorrent sync is not starting after i login

Tags: sync, bittorrent

Bitorrent is not starting after i log in to my computer
I already tried to start it with service start btsync but is not working!

how can i make Bit torrent sync to start when Ubuntu starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its an old question but I just fixed by reinstalling BTSYNC, everything was good after that.